# Select from python is retrieving wrong form

Tags: python, double, firebird, kinterbasdb

I'm working with the Firebird database, and I would like to know how to fix a format from an SELECT query. The SELECT query is returning this from the `isql`

```
           NU_INSCRICAO
=======================

      4228949000102.000
```

But in my software, is returning:

```
4.2289490001e+012
```

I actually don't understand what the +012 means, also.

Comment: In your software, it is returning in exponential form. +012 indicates how many digits it moved the decimal from its original position.

Comment: In other words `4.2289490001*10^12`

Comment: It is the same value, it is just displayed differently by Python, see the link in my previous comment how to display it differently.